# How can I automatically push changes from a remote repository to Github?

Tags: git, ssh, cron, push

I have been trying using crontab to automatically run a bash script that pushes changes into github. When I run the script in the shell command line, it works perfectly. But it isn´t working with crontab.

This is my crontab file (it is executing every 2 minutes because of testing purposes):

```
*/2 * * * * ./script.sh
```

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/repo.git
git push origin
```

Because of testing purposes I removed the passphrase for the ssh key for the connection with github

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ git push -q origin
```

That is, assuming that `git` is in a standard directory.  Otherwise, add the whole path. Also, check the output in `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 0):

add the full path to your script in

```
*/2 * * * * ./script.sh
```

and add a `touch /tmp/my-check-file` to the script, to see if it actually runs.